# Autoscroll in recycler view when dragging a view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler-view inside a constraint-layout. 
I can drag and drop items in my recycler view, but whenever I am dragging an item, If i get to the very bottom of the screen or to the top of the screen , recycler view doesn't scroll automatically.

Things I have tried and failed:

I have read somewhere that I should disable nestedscrollview of the recyclerview.

I tried setting a a drag listener on the recycler view:

```
//            @Override
//            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
//                if (event.getAction()== DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) {
//
//                    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter =  recyclerView.getAdapter();
//                    int y = Math.round(event.getY());
//
//                    int translatedY = y - recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollExtent();
//
//                    int threshold = 50;
//                    // make a scrolling up due the y has passed the threshold
//                    if (translatedY < threshold) {
//                        // make a scroll up by 30 px
//                        recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, -30);
//
//                    } else
//                        // make a autoscrolling down due y has passed the 500 px border
//                        if (translatedY + threshold > 500) {
//                            // make a scroll down by 30 px
//                            recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, 30);
//                        }
//                return true;
//                }else {
//                    return false;
//                }
//
//            }
//        });
```